# When should この世 be Heiban or Odaka?

Tags: pitch-accent

Dictionaries list この世 as either Heiban or Odaka, presumably because 世 can either be Heiban or Odaka. Are there rules of thumb for when 世/この世 should be used in either its Odaka or Heiban forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern standard Japanese, 世 is accented (よ＼) and この世 is 尾高 (このよ＼).

One might wonder what the point of considering この世 as its own word is since the location of the accent doesn’t change, but there is a good reason.

世, when followed by a の stays accented (as is usual for a one-mora word), while この世 loses its accent when followed by a の (as is usual for almost all odaka words):

- このよ＼は
- このよの
- よ＼は
- よ＼の

This is good enough reason to consider この世 its own lexical item because otherwise there would be no way to account for this (as this does *not* normally happen with この — e.g., この木の would be このき＼の).

あの世 behaves the same as この世.

Comment: So as a rough rule, ((Odaka word) + の) becomes Heiban, *so long as* the Odaka word is more than 1 mora?  And (1-mora Odaka word + の) doesn't become Heiban?

Comment: I have an older (I think?) version of the NHK pitch accent dictionary, and it states that この世を needn't be accented on the よ (either Heiban or an accent on the よ is correct). NHK also usually (I think?) talks about pitch accent changes with の, and doesn't mention this.  So basically I'm learning that NHK doesn't cover everything.

Comment: Here is what I'm seeing from NHK: https://imgur.com/a/21sHsgp Do you know why it's saying この世を (Heiban) is acceptable?

Comment: Re: “So as a rough rule” — yes. Alternatively you can choose to think of the accented single-mora words as 頭高, and then no exception is required for them.

Comment: Re: NHK, I think it’s simply outdated. 新明解国語辞典 also listed [0][3] in their seventh edition but updated it to [3] in their eighth edition. NHK has listed [0][3] since their 1998 edition so it was probably just never updated, especially due to being a somewhat uncommon word in the news.

Comment: Personally I’ve never heard この世を said heiban by anyone, including newscasters.

Comment: Do you know if もの and こと follows this rule (odaka)?